# Determining whether a multivariable function is onto

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

A problem is asking me to identify whether the following function is onto: $$ R^2 -> R^2$$    $$f(x,y)=(x+y,2x+2y) $$

I understand the definition of onto (each real number solution in a certain domain being corresponded to) and it makes sense enough, when given ordinary linear equations like $$y = x^2 $$

which is not onto, considering no negative values of y can be reached. This can easily be seen graphically.  I'm more confused when given a function of more than one variable, such as the one above or 
$$R^3->R^3 $$
$$f(x,y,z)=(x+y,y+z,x+z) $$

Can I get some help putting these functions in similar terms to the y = 3x case?

Comment: Without knowing the codomain it's impossible to say whether $f$ is onto or not.  But assuming the codomain is supposed to be $\Bbb R^2$, can you see some relationship between the $x$ and $y$ components of $f(x,y)$ that may prohibit you from "reaching" certain points in the space?  **Bonus points:** since $f$ (in both of your examples) is linear, we can construct a matrix $A$ which represents $f$ wrt the standard basis.  Can you see how $A$ may give you some ideas about whether $f$ is onto or not?

Comment: @Bye_World technically the functions are multi-linear ?

Comment: @JamesDickens No, the functions are linear.  Try $f((x_1, y_1)+\lambda (x_2,y_2))$ and see if you get $f(x_1, y_1) + \lambda f(x_2,y_2)$.  Then try $f(x_1 + \lambda x_2, y)$ and see if you get $f(x_1,y) + \lambda f(x_2,y)$.  One will work and the other won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f: R^2 \rightarrow R^2$, $f(x,y)=(x+y, 2x+2y)=(x+y,2(x+y))$, I claim that is it not onto.

For example, we cannot find preimage of $f$ for $(0,1)$ since the second entry is not equal to twice of the first entry.

For $f: R^3 \rightarrow R^3$, $f(x,y, z)=(x+y,y+z,z+x)=(x,y,z)\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, the question is now given $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$, am I able to find $(x,y,z)$ such that $$(x,y,z)A=(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)$$

verify that $A$ is non-singular, and you can indeed compute

$$(x,y,z)=(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)A^{-1}$$

Hence, it is onto.

Edit:

$$x+y = \alpha$$
$$y+z = \beta$$
$$x+z = \gamma$$

where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are given and we want to solve for $x,y,z$.

One possible way to solve for this problem is to first sum everything up and divides by $2$. We obtain

$$x+y+z=\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}{2}$$

$$(x+y+z)-(x+y)=z=\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}{2}-\alpha$$

Similarly, we can solve for $x$ and $y$

Comment: I folllow your work up to the creation of the matrix, but I haven't learned what it means for a matrix to be non-singular or how to verify that.

Comment: Edited my answer to avoid using matrices. The goal is to solve for $x,y,z$.